# How to create helm template for a yaml block?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am trying to create a helm chart which will deploy the secretProviderClass on the K8s cluster. the problem i am facing while trying to template the below section:

```yaml
objects:  |
  array:
    - |
      objectName: secret1
      objectType: secret
    - |
      objectName: secret2
      objectType: secret
```

My Value file:

```yaml
vault:
  secrets:
.   array:
      - |
        objectName: secret1
        objectType: secret
      - |
        objectName: secret2
        objectType: secret
```

In my helm template:

```yaml
objects:  |
  array:
    {{ .Values.vault.secrets.array | toJson | nindent 6 }}
```

```
Error: at <.Values.vault.secrets.array>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.array
```

How can i solve this? Can somebody please help?

Comment: The error message suggests that `vault: { secrets: }` isn't defined in your `values.yaml` file (but that a top-level `vault:` key is defined, and has a map value).  Can you double-check this part of your setup?

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the comment. I have the variables defined in the values.yaml file as mentioned above and there is no other vault: key defined in the file.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate your scenario and during copy/paste I've noticed that your values are invalid because of an "." before vault.secrets.array

```
vault:
  secrets:
# Notice the invalid "." which prevents .array from beeing accessed
==> . <==   array:
      - |
        objectName: secret1
        objectType: secret
      - |
        objectName: secret2
        objectType: secret
```

When I remove the "." from your values file example and render a helm template with the snippet you provided, it works.

values.yaml:

```
---
vault:
  secrets:
    array:
      - |
        objectName: secret1
        objectType: secret
      - |
        objectName: secret2
        objectType: secret
```

template:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cm
data:
  objects: |
    array:
      {{ .Values.vault.secrets.array | toJson | nindent 6 }}
```

helm template result:

```
helm template <chartName>/
---
# Source: <chartName>/templates/cm.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: myapp
data:
  objects: |
    array:
      
      ["objectName: secret1\nobjectType: secret\n","objectName: secret2\nobjectType: secret\n"]
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the response. I dont have the extra "." on my actual values.yaml file. Perhaps it is a typo while posting the question here. Sorry for the inconvenience.  I fixed the issue by updating "nindent" from 6 to 10.  Thank you!